# How to get past "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" Error Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Total React Noob here, just trying to underline all of the titles in my array as well as add an onclick function to them, but I keep getting the "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression" error, what am I doing wrong??

```
const result_html = [];
  const link_underline = {
    color: 'blue',
    textDecoration: 'underline',
    cursor: 'pointer'
  };

  


  for (let  result of props.results) {
    result_html.push(<li key={result.job_id.raw}>{result.business_title.raw}</li>);
    result_html.push(<li key={result.job_id.raw}>{result.job_description.raw}</li>);
    result_html.push(<li key={result.job_id.raw}>{result.preferred_skills.raw}</li>);
    <span style={link_underline} onClick={result.job_id.raw}>{result.business_title.raw}</span>
    
  }
  


  return (
    <main className="main main--details">
      <h2>Results:</h2>
      <ul>
        {result_html}
      </ul>
      <div>
      </div>
    </main>
  );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

the 4th line in your for loop is just an element with no assignment, move it into the `return` statement or push it to the `result_html`

Comment: @Stack445678 I recommend you take the time to setup ESLint in your environment. It's admittedly a real pain to get working initially, but it will be your best friend in spotting these errors.

Comment: Moving it to the return statement results in a 'results not defined' error since results is only located in my for loop, and pushing it into my result_html makes the loop stop working for some reason.

Comment: you should wrap that line with an `<li>` tag if you are going to nest it in the `<ul>`, then the push should work

Comment: It no longer loops by the job id like it's supposed to, also it didn't change the title at all no Onclick event and no underline :(

Answer (score 0):

The real issue if that you want to follow the react component pattern here, try splitting the for loop out and creating a component to display just a single result and you will find it much easier to build on.

```
  const Result = props => {
    const link_underline = {
      color: 'blue',
      textDecoration: 'underline',
      cursor: 'pointer'
    };
    const { result } = props;
    return (
      <ul>
        <li key={result.job_id.raw}>{result.business_title.raw}</li>
        <li key={result.job_id.raw}>{result.job_description.raw}</li>
        <li key={result.job_id.raw}>{result.preferred_skills.raw}</li>
        <li><span style={link_underline} onClick={result.job_id.raw}>{result.business_title.raw}</span></li>
      </ul>
    )
  }

// in the original component

return (
  <main className="main main--details">
    <h2>Results:</h2>
    {results.map((result, i) => <Result key={i} result={result} />)}
    <div>
    </div>
  </main>
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering! Unfortunately I tried something just like this earlier (just went ahead and tested yours to be sure) and I get the error 'results is not defined' in the for loop it only existed in the loop and in this case I'm not too sure why I'm getting that error

Comment: are you getting results in an ajax call? can you post that logic?

Comment: Wait! I got it to work! Thank you so much for your help!